# add setTimeout to google tag manager manually

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-tag-manager

Loading in Wordpress tag manager, and I want to add a setTimeout to load the script 5 seconds later.

```
    echo "<script>(function(w, d, s, l, i) {
    w[l] = w[l] || [];
    w[l].push({
        'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
        event: 'gtm.js'
    });
    var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j = d.createElement(s),
        dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
    j.async = true;
    j.src =
        'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
    f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
})(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-code');</script>";
```

second part:

```
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-code"
        height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
```

Comment: I think you should remove the second part. Loading the noscript tag with Javascript makes little sense, for reasons that should be obvious.

Comment: Google Tag Manager ask to put the two codes above. One in the head and one in the opening body.

Comment: The second part is only executed when there is no Javascript - that is what "noscript" means. So there is no point in loading it via a Javascript timeout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful with loading GTM late.  If a user visits your site for just a few seconds and then leaves, it is called a "bounce" in Google Analytics.  If GTM doesn't load in time to send a page view to Google Analytics, you can have an artificially low [bounce rate](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009409?hl=en).  You may want to consider other options to whatever problem you're solving before delaying GTM.

Having said that, here's some code that should work.  :)

```php
echo "<script>
var loadGtm = function(w, d, s, l, i) {
  w[l] = w[l] || [];
  w[l].push({
    'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
    event: 'gtm.js'
  });
  var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
      j = d.createElement(s),
      dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
  j.async = true;
  j.src = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
  f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
}
setTimeout(loadGtm.bind(null, window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-code'), 5000);
</script>";
```

As [@Eike Pierstorff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/761212) said, it doesn't make sense to load the `noscript` tag with `setTimeout`.  If javascript is enabled, that tag won't do anything.  If javascript is disabled, the `setTimeout` won't work so the `noscript` tag won't get added.  I would just add it to the `body` as-is.

Comment: Do you think is better to load GTM on window.scroll event?

Comment: Not really.  If possible I think loading it immediately is the best way to go.  May I ask why you need to delay it?

Comment: I'm getting a lower score in Lighthouse.

Comment: Oh, ok.  Using `setTimeout()` makes sense to me, but you could try shortening the timeout to 2 seconds or something to get more accurate numbers.